# I want to execute groovy script (present on a server1 ) on server2 which is not having groovy installed in it

Tags: groovy

Is it possible? OR is there any method to do so like by using jenkins or other.Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is like "I want to drink lemon juice with water, but I have no water, is this possible?". No, it is not possible. Either you have Groovy available, then you can execute Groovy scripts, or you don't have it then you cannot.

If you have Jenkins, then you *do* have Groovy, even if not installed separately.

Comment: If groovy is installed on server 2 then does it possible?...I have asked another question for it on stackoverflow though,but don't know when you will get to see that....@Vampire

Comment: Of course it is, why not. If you have some means to copy and execute it there that is. e. g. copy the script to server2 via scp and then execute it via ssh to name one example. And I don't see all questions on SO, I have a live also, you know. ;-)

Comment: scp and ssh commands works on Linux server but both of my Servers are windows Server.Please suggest a way ..sorry to disturb you again ;-)...@Vampire

Comment: You can also use them on Windows if you install the accoring services. With Windows board tools I cannot say, I prevent using Windows if I can, especially on servers.